# jQuery switchClass and background images

Tags: jquery-ui

I want to change an element's class, and have the new class swap in a different background image. I do not care about animating the change (background images cannot be animated in any case--see below). But I do want to invoke a callback function after the class change (and its css effects) have fully taken effect.

`Not all styles can be animated. For example, there is no way to animate a background image. Any styles that cannot be animated will be changed at the end of the animation.`

http://api.jqueryui.com/switchClass/

Do I understand correctly, that the switchClass callback function's execution and the change of background style could be ongoing concurrently?  There's no way to figure out when the background image style change has been *completed*?

Comment: JQuery simply switches the class name. Any changes in background associated with the class are nothing to do with it.

Comment: This DOM interface would be nice to have:  `element.classList.add('class', callbackFunction)` where the callbackFunction would be invoked when the effects of the change of class had been completed.